# 'dict' object has no attribute 'append' Json

Tags: python, json

I have this code that adds 50 points to a user in my json file but I keep getting a `'dict' object has no attribute 'append'` when trying to append new users to the users:

```
def updateUsers(chan):
    j = urllib2.urlopen('http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/' + chan + '/chatters')
    j_obj = json.load(j)
    with open('dat.dat', 'r') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        for dat in data['users']:
            if dat in j_obj['chatters']['moderators'] or j_obj['chatters']['viewers']:
                data['users']['tryhard_cupcake']['Points'] += 50
            else:
                data['users'].append([dat]) # append doesn't work here
    with open('dat.dat', 'w') as out_file:
        json.dump(data, out_file)
```

What is the proper way of adding new objects/users to `users`?

Comment: The code here... doesn't make any sense. You're iterating over keys that are by definition already in `data['users']`, and then potentially trying to append them to `data['users']`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy appending stuff to a dict doesn't require me to say the structure

Comment: You **can't** append a list to a dict. Not. Possible. So, we need to figure out what you _actually_ want to do (as opposed to the impossible thing you *think* you want to do), and for that we need structure.

Comment: Even better would be explicit description of intent ("my initial data is X, I want to modify it to look like Y").

Comment: ...I mean, I don't even know what you expect the result of appending a list to a dict to be. If it's appending a value, how does it get the key to use? If it's a new key, where does it get a value? And if we don't know what you expect, how can we tell you how to achieve that thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234473/python-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-append)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error message has your answer.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

```
 data['users'] = [dat]
```

If you want to append to the existing list.

```
templist = data['users']
templist.extend(dat)
data['users'] = templist
```

Comment: Your code overwrites the old data rather than add new data?

Comment: You should be using a list for appending . Dictionary has a key value pair and keys should be unique.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `data['users']` is a dictionary, so you can only use dictionary methods to add keys and values.