# Python AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, tuples

I am creating a loop in order to append continuously values from user input to a dictionary but i am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

This is my code so far:

```
    for index, elem in enumerate(main_feeds):
        print(index,":",elem)
        temp_list = index,":",elem
    li = {}
    print_user_areas(li)

    while True:
        n = (input('\nGive number: '))


        if n == "":
          break
        else:
             if n.isdigit():
               n=int(n)
               print('\n')
               print (main_feeds[n])

               temp = main_feeds[n]
               for item in user:


                  user['areas'].append[temp]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, a dict doesn't have an append method. And even if it did, you couldn't call it with square brackets.

Comment: use defaultdict instead (with list in it)

Comment: You assign values to a dict using its key like this : `user['areas'] = temp`. Your code would only work IF `user[areas]` was already a list. If you need it to be a list, construct the list first, THEN assign that list to the key.

Answer (score 34):

Like the error message suggests, dictionaries in Python do not provide an append operation.

You can instead just assign new values to their respective keys in a dictionary.

```
mydict = {}
mydict['item'] = input_value
```

If you're wanting to append values as they're entered you could instead use a list.

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(input_value)
```

Your line `user['areas'].append[temp]` looks like it is attempting to access a dictionary at the value of key `'areas'`, if you instead use a list you should be able to perform an append operation.

Using a list instead:

```
user['areas'] = []
```

On that note, you might want to check out the possibility of using a `defaultdict(list)` for your problem. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work)

Comment: Dictionaries in Python _do_ provide an `update` method though.  So, if you want to add more key-value pairs: `dict.update({'another_key': 'another_value'})`.  Maybe of value here.  `update` will overwrite existing keys of the same name, so _caveat emptor_.

Comment: Very true Matt! Although, it looks like they're trying to just append values here.

Answer (score 3):

As the error suggests, `append` is not a method or attribute, meaning you cannot call `append` in the dictionary `user`.
Instead of

```
user['areas'].append[temp]
```

Use

```
user['areas'].update[temp]
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error and the fellows pointed out, there is no 'append' attribute to a 'dict' object.

But if you really see a Python code with the line `dict["key"].append(value)` working, it is because there is a `list` inside this key, and you want to specifically **add values in the list inside the key** (not to add new entries to the key itself). Then `dict["key"].append(value)` will work anyway.

Answer (score -7):

Either 
use dict.setdefault() if the key is not added yet to dictionary :

```
dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)
```

or use, if you already have the keys set up:

```
dict[key].append(value)
```

source: stackoverflow answers

Comment: you should at least add a link to which answer from stackoverflow you're refering to