# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

```
Can someone please tell me what basic thing I am missing here.

Type: <class 'list'>
Value : ['09,10,11,12,13,14,15']

for datapoint in value:
    y.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(datapoint).strftime('%I%P').lstrip('0').upper())

I want value of y should be like this-[9PM,10PM,11PM,12PM,1PM,2PM,3PM]
```

I am not sure why its is not converting to the value I want, if I am using above function. Can someone please suggest what I am missing here and why I am getting this error -> "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: `y` should be a `list` not a `dict`

Comment: @PatrickArtner I m not sure of that

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['dict' object has no attribute 'append'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676526/dict-object-has-no-attribute-append)

Answer (score 1):

You have a 1-element list with a string in it: your `datapoint` is the single whole string, not pieces of it. You need to split and iterate over the splitted values:

```
from datetime import datetime

y = [] # use list to use append, see dict approach below

data = '09,10,11,12,13,14,15'.split(",") #split into ["09","10",...,"15"]

for dp in data: # "09" then "10" then "11" etc.
    y.append(datetime.strptime(dp,"%H").strftime('%I%P').strip("0").upper())

print(y)
```

Output:

```
['9AM', '10AM', '11AM', '12PM', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM']
```

To add that do a dictionary you need to use `update((key,value)-iterable)` or `d[key]=value`:

```
d = {}
for time in y:
    d["Time "+time] = time

# or

d.update(  ((t,t) for t in y) ) # doesnt make much sense to have identical key/values

# d[]=... - Output
{'Time 9AM': '9AM', 'Time 12PM': '12PM', 'Time 3PM': '3PM', 
 'Time 11AM': '11AM', 'Time 2PM': '2PM', 'Time 10AM': '10AM', 
 'Time 1PM': '1PM'}

# update - Output 
{'12PM': '12PM', '1PM': '1PM', '11AM': '11AM', '9AM': '9AM', 
 '10AM': '10AM', '3PM': '3PM', '2PM': '2PM'}
```

Comment: I tried the first one but I again getting the attribute error
    data = value.split(",") #split into ["09","10",...,"15"]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: print(value)
['09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16']

Comment: @Terry what do you want to tell me? `data = value[0].split(",")` then rest of the code as above ...

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, you are trying to use `append()` on the variable `y` which is here a dictionary. Dictionaries do not have an `append()` function, hence the error.

In order for your code to work, you probably need `y` to be a `list`.