# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append' in json

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

Append does not work on dictionary object. My code is as follow:

```
with open (file) as f:
    for line in f:
        review = json.loads(line)
        review.append((review['reviewText'],review['overall']))#append is not working
        review[5]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['dict' object has no attribute 'append' Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640689/dict-object-has-no-attribute-append-json)

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary object has no `append` method. You can add key,value to a dictionary such as follow:

```
review["you_key"] = your_value
```